# integrate attribute of xarray

Tags: python, attributes, python-xarray, integrate

I am new to xarray and need it to handle larger netcdf files. I have one with dimensions 'time','level','latitude', and 'longitude'. I try to integrate along the 'level' dimension below and get an error that a 'DataArray' object has no attribute 'integrate'. From [this page](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.integrate.html#xarray.DataArray.integrate) I understand that it does. Very simple code below. Thanks for any help.

```
dataDIR = basedir + 'vt_' + str(yr) + monstr + '_sub.nc'
DS = xr.open_dataset(dataDIR)
vt = DS.v
ivt = vt.integrate('level')
```

Comment: What version of xarray are you using? `integrate` was added in v0.12. You can print the version number like this: `print(xr.__version__)`.

Comment: yup, that'll do it. thanks so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `integrate` method was added in Xarray v0.12. Upgrading to (at least) that version should fix your problem.

```
pip install -U xarray
```

or

```
conda update -c conda-forge xarray
```